# Can I capture program invocation and execution externally?

Tags: operating-system, runtime, ipc

What is the best way to capture the invocation of an external program? I want to avoid polling through commands like ps. Are there any libraries that are event-driven and generate events whenever a program gets executed.

As for an example, assume there's a program P. Now I put a hook in the library for P and whenever P is executed I receive events regarding the execution of P.

Comment: what platform will u be using ?

Answer (score 1):

You should start by

1. looking into `----> auditd'

   run after start up to create logs`auditctl -a task,always`
2. http://tldp.yolinux.com/HOWTO/Process-Monitor-HOWTO.html